# Is invariant theory OK in positive characteristic?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, invariant-theory

Let G be a connected reductive group over an algebraically closed field of characteristic p.  Let X = Spec(A) be an affine variety over the same field, with an action of G.

Are the closed points in Spec(A^G) in one-to-one correspondence with the closed orbits in X?